# scrapy + adbapi = AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DictCursor'

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a CrawlSpider I setup with an item pipeline and I'm trying to persist to via MySQLdb. I have searched all over and most of the samples I find are at least 6 months old, all using adbapi in the same fashion. When I attempt to use the same format, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DictCursor'
```

I'm not seeing what I'm doing wrong here but I'm fairly new to Python and very new to scrapy so it's completely possible it's something simple I'm overlooking.

```
from twisted.enterprise import adbapi
from scrapy import log

import MySQLdb.cursors

class InventoryPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.pool = adbapi.ConnectionPool('MySQLdb',
                db='inventory',
                user='root',
                passwd='',
                cursorClass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor,
                charset="utf8",
                use_unicode=True
            )


    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        query = self.pool.runInteraction(self._insert_record, item)
        query.addErrback(self._handle_error)
        return item


    def _insert_record(self, tx, item):
        tx.execute("select * from content where url = %s", (item['url']))
        result = tx.fetchone()
        if result:
            log.msg("url already in database", level=log.INFO)
        else:
            tx.execute("insert into content (url, title, link_content, main_content, header) values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                (item['url'], item['title'], item['link_content'], item['main_content'], item['header']))
            log.msg("Item stored in db: %s" % item, level=log.INFO)
        return item


    def _handle_error(self, e):
        log.err(e)
```

Comment: BTW - I also tried it including "import MySQLdb" as well as the "import MySQLdb.cursors" to no avail.

Comment: This is weird. What if you import both: `import MySQLdb` and `import MySQLdb.cursors`?

Comment: btw, what `mysqldb` version are you using?

Comment: Server version: 5.5.15 MySQL Community Server on my MacBook Pro

Comment: Ok, but I mean the python module itself - `mysqldb`.

Comment: Python 2.7.2 & MySQL-python 1.3.0 - sorry I misunderstood

Comment: Where does this MySQL-python 1.3.0 release come from? from source from https://github.com/farcepest/MySQLdb1/tree/MySQLdb-1.3? On PyPi I only see up to 1.2.4

Answer (score 0):

i have met this problem too and I solved it.

You can try this

from MySQLdb.cursors import DictCursor

and change cursorClass to "cursorClass=DictCursor"

It works on my computer,I hope it will also help u and other guys